# There is a border around my buttons and when I click somewhere on the screen it disappears

Tags: html, css, button, border, styling

I am having a problem, where there is a border(different in different browsers, blue in safari, a dotted black in chrome) around my buttons when they first load. I am guessing it's some sort of selecting but I want to disable it. How can I do so, that there is no border on the initial loading of the buttons. Here is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Please add a piece of code or a link to your website

Comment: Please share the code. from looking at it it looks like an outline so just add CSS for button outline: 0; OR outline: none;

Answer (score 1):

It is called an outline. Try this:

```
button:focus {outline:0 !important;}
```

Worth noting that this will become an accessibility issue if removed.

Answer (score 0):

This border is an outline. It's provided by browsers
You can also use:

```
button:focus {outline: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for more information.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp)

If you want to remove it, use this.

```css
.buttonclass {
outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonclass">Button</button>
```

If you want to keep it but you don't want that it should be visible, use this.

```css
.buttonclass:focus {
outline:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonclass">Button</button>
```

However I don't think a button has an outline.